# Update class attribute when other attributes change without @property

Tags: python, class, properties

Suppose I have a class with three attributes, at_1, at_2 and at_3, and at_3 depends on the other two in a complex way. When I initialize the class with at_1 and at_2, I call a method also defined in the class that computes at_3. Something like that would do the work:

```
class My_class:
    def __init__(self,at_1,at_2)
        self.at_1=at_1
        self.at_2=at_2
        self.at_3=self.some_complicated_function(at_1,at_2)

    def some_complicated_function(self,at_1,at_2):
        return at_1+at_2
```

Now, I would like that if I change either at_1 or at_2, at_3 is updated accordingly. One option is to define at_3 with the `@property` decorator, but this implies that every time I want to look for at_3 the `some_complicated_function` has to be executed again. I would like something like: "if any attribute changes, rerun `some_complicated_function` and update at_3 as an attribute."

Is there a way to do so? (bottom line, I want to automatically run a function in a class if any attribute changes)

Comment: You could create a `set` method for each attribute. Each time a `set` method is called, you can check there if the argument value is different than the attribute's value and if so, rerun the computations for the 3rd attribute. Kind of similar to setting private members in a C++ class if you are familiar with the concept.

Comment: You have confused class attributes and instance attributes.